# Dart null safety - retrieving value from map in a null safe way

Tags: dart, dart-null-safety

I had code similar to this example code (never mind that it makes no sense):

```dart
void foo(Map<int, String> myMap) {
  String s = myMap[1];
}
```

The dart analyzer warns me about the line `String s = myMap[1];` with the following warning:

> A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type
> 'String'.  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the
> right-hand type to 'String'.

I see that this is happening because retrieving a value from a map can result in `null`. Why does the following snippet give me the same warning?

```dart
void foo(Map<int, String> myMap) {
  if (myMap.containsKey(1)) {
    String s = myMap[1];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is based entirely on the *type* of the operation. The `operator []` of a `Map<K,V>` returns a `V?`, so it might be `null`.
The type system doesn't know whether the key is in the map or not, or even what a map *is*.

That you call another method which implies that the return value won't be `null` doesn't change the type, and the compiler doesn't get that implication.

Answer (score 15):

**Problem:**

From the [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#the-map-index-operator-is-nullable):

> The index [] operator on the Map class returns null if the key isn’t present. This implies that the return type of that operator must be nullable.

Take a look at the following code. Since the key `b` is missing from the `Map`, `map['b']` returns `null` and assigning its value to `int` would have caused `runtime` error if this had passed the static analysis.

```dart
Map<String, int> map = {'a': 1};
int i = map['b']; // Error: You can't assign null to a non-nullable field.
```

---

**Solutions:**

- Use **`??`** and provide a default value (recommended)

  ```dart
  int i = map['b'] ?? 0;
  ```
- Use the Bang **`!`** operator.

  ```dart
  int i = map['b']!; // Caution! It causes runtime error if there's no key.
  ```

Comment: "Use ?? and provide a default value (recommended)" Recommended by the official docs? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: @AlexJean Docs doesn't **recommend** `??` explicitly but using it is much safer than using the bang operator.

Answer (score 4):

Thing is that compiler does not know that map's method **containsKey** really does.

Theoretically you could pass some weird Map's implementation having  **containsKey** which does something else than checking if value exists.

Compiler will not produce warning only if it 100% sure that value might not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I was primed by languages where trying to use `myMap[key]` for a nonexistent key would throw an error. In that case a possible pattern is to check first if the key is present (although this can be problematic in multithreaded code). But here such a check is not necessary -- one can simply test if the value is not `null`.

```dart
void foo(Map<int, String> myMap) {
  if (myMap[1]  != null) {
    String s = myMap[1];
  }
}
```

See a good explanation along those lines on the dartlang github https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44444.
Also the official faq for null savety https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#how-do-i-signal-that-the-return-value-from-a-map-is-non-nullable

Answer (score 0):

Best way is that you can create your Map's Extension. Also, you can pass a optional value when key is not found. This style is basically **Python like get on dictonary**.

```
dynamic get(String key, {dynamic opt}) {
    if (this.containsKey(key)) {
      return this[key];
    }
    return opt;
  }
}
```

Now in different file, you can import it & use it.

```
dynamic val = map.get('my_key', opt: 'other_value');
```