# Why it's showing error on my Flutter project?

Tags: flutter

This is my code:

```
import 'package:alselre/constants.dart';
import 'package:alselre/size_config.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  const Body({super.key});

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  int currentPage = 0;
  List<Map<String, String>> splashData = [
    {
      "text": "Welcome to alSelre \nThe best platform to buy anything!",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_1.png"
    },
    {
      "text": "You'll get fastest delivery with 24/7 customer service.",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_2.png"
    },
    {
      "text": "You'll get the best products \nfrom all over the country",
      "image": "assets/images/splash_3.png"
    },
  ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: PageView.builder(
                itemCount: splashData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
                  image: splashData[index]["image"],
                  text: splashData[index]['text'],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: SizedBox(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SplashContent extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashContent({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.image,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String text, image;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Spacer(),
        Text(
          "alSelre",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: getProportionateScreenWidth(36),
            color: kPrimaryColor,
            fontFamily: "Quebecks",
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Muli",
          ),
        ),
        Spacer(
          flex: 2,
        ),
        Image.asset(
          image,
          height: getProportionateScreenHeight(265),
          width: getProportionateScreenWidth(235),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And I'm having this error:
lib/screens/splash/components/body.dart:39:43: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
image: splashData[index]["image"],
^
lib/screens/splash/components/body.dart:40:42: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
text: splashData[index]['text'],
^

And I'm having this error:
lib/screens/splash/components/body.dart:39:43: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
image: splashData[index]["image"],
^
lib/screens/splash/components/body.dart:40:42: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.
text: splashData[index]['text'],
^

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart null safety - retrieving value from map in a null safe way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65235879/dart-null-safety-retrieving-value-from-map-in-a-null-safe-way)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```dart
 itemBuilder: (context, index) => SplashContent(
                  image: "${splashData[index]["image"]}",
                  text: "${splashData[index]['text']}",
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The List of Map can be nullable so, you cannot assign that to place where it's accepting non nullable value.
You can update your code as below

```
SplashContent(
                  image: splashData[index]["image"] ?? 'DEFAULT_IMAGE',
                  text: splashData[index]['text'] ?? 'DEFAULT_TEXT',
                ),
```

you can set default text and image. So, when value will be null it will use that default values.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is likely due to the fact that the type of the value you are trying to pass (**splashData[0]['text']**) is inferred as **String?** (nullable String), but the parameter of your widget is expecting a non-nullable **String**.

In Dart, when you access a value using the index operator ([]), the type of the result is nullable if the key is not guaranteed to exist in the map. This is because accessing a key in a map might return null if the key is not present.

To resolve this issue, you can use the null-aware operator (**??**) to provide a default value if the key is not present. Here's an example:

```
String text = splashData[0]['text'] ?? "";
```

This way, if `splashData[0]['text']` is null, it will use an empty string as a default value.

Alternatively, if you are certain that the keys always exist in your map, you can assert non-null using the `!` operator:

```
String text = splashData[0]['text']!;
```

But be cautious when using the **!** operator. It should only be used when you are absolutely sure that the value is non-null, as it will cause a runtime error if the value is actually **null**.

Choose the approach that best fits your use case based on your understanding of the data and whether the keys are guaranteed to exist in your maps.